# Python dictionary keys fast access

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary -

```
myDictry = {}
myDictry[4] = 88
myDictry[14] = 7
myDictry[5] = 102
myDictry[49] = 3
```

i need to to get the second-largest key of this dictionary. so - in the above case, i gotta access the key 14 and go from there.

currently doing it as -

```
list(myDictry.keys())[-2]
```

is this the best way - is/n't there a more "Pythonic" way of doing this?

is Python sorting the `dict.keys` every time i call `myDictry.keys()` or keeping them sorted(my guess)?

what about when i call `max(myDictry)`?

not yet that old in Python.excuse if too naive.

UPDATE

been adding keys in increasing order- wasn't careful w/that.
got my answer. thx to contributors.

Comment: Dictionaries are not designed for efficiently accessing keys, but rather, for efficiently accessing a value associated with a known key. The "pythonic" way is not to use a dictionary. Python *does not sort the keys*. In general, you should think of dictionaries as unordered data structures, indeed they are, however, in Python 3.7 + dictionaries are guaranteed to maintain *insertion order*.

Comment: OrderedDict might work.

Comment: keys are not sorted.  Order used to undefined, now it is determined by order of creation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is useful. write it as an answer

Comment: As mentioned the keys are not kept in sorted order.  To find the second largest you can either sort the keys in descending order and take the 2nd element (sorting is O(N*log(N)), or you can use [this method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-largest-smallest-second-largest-second-smallest-list/) to find the second largest in O(N).

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Attempts made using `list.sort()` and `sorted()` and also adding checks to see if there are more than one item in list.

Using list.sort()

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[4] = 88
my_dict[14] = 7
my_dict[5] = 102
my_dict[49] = 3

key_list = list(my_dict.keys())
key_list.sort()  # In-place sorting of list
if len(key_list) > 1:
    print(key_list[-2])
```

Using `sorted()`

```
key_list = sorted(my_dict.keys())  # It sorts iterable of **similar** types
if len(key_list) > 1:
    print(key_list[-2])
```

output:

```
14
```